# When I used TPH, all the tables recreated

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am developing an EF - MVC 3 application. I have used **model first approach**, so I have create model first and from that model, EF generated the DB.

I have used a tool called Nuget - Entity Generator - Database designer for generating the database. When I have designed the model first time, I have used the Generate Migration T-SQL and Deploy option of that tool.

Database generated perfectly and it's working fine...

Now I have come across a situation that I have to make a change to the model and I have to use T-SQL Via T4 (TPH) option to update the database.

[image]
So previously I used different process to update DB and now I am changing it.

When I use the T-SQL Via T4 (TPH) all the tables get deleted and new tables get created. 
How to avoid this ?

I want to only update the table which I have made the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity framework 4.3 comes with migration support. This is not available in EF 4.1.

Some links from google:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: I have downloaded the entity framework 5.0 but still table gets droped and creates the new record. Is the issue regarding EF 5.0 or its realted to Database Genration Workflow Manager v1.1 ?